# Webpack & React getComponent() not loading component (async)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router

I am using Webpack 3.7.1 and React 15.6.1 and I am trying to load different components dynamically.

### What I would like to do

- Loading the components asynchronously from the different chunks webpack created when code splitting

### What i did

- Using **getComponent()** and **import()** to generate the chunks
- **Configured** the webpack.config file properly so that the chunks are created (code splitting)

### The issue

- Chunks are **generated but not loaded** properly when accessing a route
- getComponent() does not seem to work

### My Webpack.config file

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true
  },
  entry: {
    app:"./src/index.js",
    vendor: [
      "axios",
      "react",
      "react-dom",
      "react-redux",
      "react-router",
      "react-router-dom",
      "redux"
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/public/views',
    filename: '[name].js',
    chunkFilename: '[chunkhash].chunk.js',
    publicPath: "/views/"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        exclude: [/node_modules/, /pdfmake.js$/]
      },
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: "json-loader"
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: "vendor",
      minChunks: Infinity
    }),
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename:  __dirname + "/views/index.ejs",
      template: __dirname + "/views/template.ejs",
      inject: 'body',
      chunks: ['vendor', 'app'],
      chunksSortMode: 'manual'
    }),
    new PreloadWebpackPlugin({
      rel: "preload",
      include: ["vendor", "app"]
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
  ]
};
```

### My index.js file (root of my react app)

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

import promise from "redux-promise";
import reducers from "./reducers";
import AppInit from "./containers/appInit";



import ProfRegisteringModal from "./containers/modals/register_prof_explanation_modal";

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(promise)(createStore);

function errorLoading(err) {
  console.error("Dynamic page loading failed", err);
}

function loadRoute(cb) {
  return module => cb(null, module.default);
}

console.log("testst");

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
    <AppInit>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div style={{ height: "100%" }}>
          <ProfRegisteringModal />
          <Switch>
            <Route
              path="/inscription/:user"
              getComponent={(location, callback) => {
                import(
                  "./components/registering/registering_landing_page.js"
                )
                  .then(loadRoute(cb))
                  .catch(errorLoading);
              }}
            />
            <Route
              path="/inscription"
              getComponent={(location, callback) => {
                import(
                  "./components/registering/registering_landing_page.js"
                )
                  .then(loadRoute(cb))
                  .catch(errorLoading);
              }}
            />
            <Route
              path="/connexion"
              getComponent={(location, callback) => {
                import("./containers/registering/signing_in.js")
                  .then(loadRoute(cb))
                  .catch(errorLoading);
              }}
            />
            <Route
              path="/equipe"
              getComponent={(location, callback) => {
                import("./components/team_pres.js")
                  .then(loadRoute(cb))
                  .catch(errorLoading);
              }}
            />
            <Route
              path="/"
              getComponent={(location, callback) => {
                import("./containers/app_container.js")
                  .then(loadRoute(cb))
                  .catch(errorLoading);
              }}
            />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </AppInit>
  </Provider>,
  document.querySelector(".root")
);
```

This file index.js got correctly loaded as I can see the console.log("test") appearing in my console.

**None of the components are correctly loaded when accessing any of the routes.**

## Thank you very much for your help

## UPDATE

Be sure to have Babel-polyfill!! This is how I solved it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your webpack.config file seems fine. what i have done that works is create the async component in

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default function asyncComponent(importComponent) {
  class AsyncComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        component: null
      };
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
      const { default: component } = await importComponent();

      this.setState({
        component: component
      });
    }

    render() {
      const C = this.state.component;

      return C ? <C {...this.props} /> : null;
    }
  }

  return AsyncComponent;
}
```

then use is as

```
const RegisterPage = asyncComponent(() => import("./components/registering/registering_landing_page.js"));
```

I don't think Route has a `getComponent` props but i could be mistaken. Your Route statement should look like this.

```
<Route
  path="/register"
  render: props => <RegisterPage {...props} />
/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! Are you sure you can write  render: props => <RegisterPage {...props} in route, like that ?

Comment: I just did component = {RegisterPage}, works like a charm thanks !! I the the major issue I had is because i was missing babel-polyfill !!